# WPF Datagrid Cell Rendering Performance Issues

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am running into issues where i have a datagrid in my WPF application that is showing around 200 cells (10 columns, 20-40 rows depending on window size). Refreshing the view (e.g. with filters) is slow (200-400ms) when I would expect it to be significantly snappier.

Data virtualization is enabled, and if i resize my window so only 2-3 rows are visible, filters refresh instantly. This leads me to believe that virtualization and collection performance isn't my issue.

I ran the profiler, and it looks like rending each cell is very slow. Even removing my custom templates doesn't bring it down to a very reasonable level. Cells are taking 5-9ms each to render, so it adds up.

Everywhere else in the application, textblocks render in 0.0015ms or so. but in the datagrid, they are 0.15ms each, plus various other overhead. Are there any further options i can employ to improve performance for sub 60ms render times?

[image]

My datagrid object:

```
<DataGrid
    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"   
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true"
    HeadersVisibility="Column" 
    BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" 
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" 
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#1e1e1e" 
    CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
    CanUserResizeRows="False"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False"
    EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
    EnableRowVirtualization="True"
    Margin="0 6 0 0" 
    Name="dgCombatLog"
    Foreground="#ffffff"
    Background="#252526"
    RowBackground="#252526"
    AlternatingRowBackground="#2a2a2a" 
    AlternationCount="2" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    MaxWidth="2560"
    MaxHeight="1600"
    DataGrid.RowHeight="24"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    RowHeaderWidth="0"
    Grid.Row="2">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#007acc"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#007acc"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="#000000" />
            <Setter Property="Padding"  Value="2 2 2 2" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#eeeeee"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2 0 2 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Border Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ActionName}" Value="AbilityActivate" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#002036" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1c97ea" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Foreground}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="59" Header="@" Binding="{Binding RelativeTimestamp}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="166" Header="Source" Binding="{Binding Source.Name}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source.IsFriendly}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#006a03"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source.IsEnemy}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#581e26"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="19" Header="A">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Width="14" Height="14" Source="{Binding ActionIcon}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="166" Header="Target" Binding="{Binding Target.Name}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Target.IsFriendly}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#006a03"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Target.IsEnemy}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#581e26"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Ability" SortMemberPath="AbilityDisplay" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasAbilityIcon}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 5 0"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>

                        <Image Width="18" Height="18" Source="{Binding AbilityIcon}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AbilityDisplay}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="49" Header="Value" Binding="{Binding ActualValue, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#daa574"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActionName}" Value="Heal">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#32cd32"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActionName}" Value="Damage">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#db001e"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Spend">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#222222"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasNumericValues}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="49" Header="Abs" Binding="{Binding AbsValue, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#30cccd"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AbsValue}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="49" Header="Over" Binding="{Binding OverValue, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActionName}" Value="Heal">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#8fbb8f"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="49" Header="Threat" Binding="{Binding Threat, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#daa574"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Threat}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="84" Header="Effects" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Many triggers. Likely the reason. every cell is monitored all the time.

Comment: @lidqy any other way to accomplish conditional cell styles? The data is not dynamic. New events may be added to the collection, but existing records arent changed

Comment: Didn't mean to bother, triggers add listeners/eventhandlers and bindings and you have quite a few of them foreach cell. If the style settings dont change after load, you could also use a Styleselectors for the celltemplates (I would think its a little faster). Also some of the settings (MouseOver/IsSelected) could be handled by VisualStateManager - though I don't know if it'll boost performance...
You could even put the brushes and other UI stuff in the VM, though it's bad style. But it'll likely reduce the loading delay a little...

Comment: Maybe you already tried this, but if you comment out as many of the purely aesthetic triggers as you can does that improve it? I agree with @lidqy it's a lot of triggers but on modern hardware I wouldn't expect it to be a problem.

Comment: Also have you tried running without attaching the debugger? I have found that makes a huge difference especially if I have a lot of binding errors or anything else really filling up the console.

Comment: Tried to localize what does slow down the `DataGrid`? Reducing columns number e.g., may be one particular column does slow down the grid, e.g. with image. Does it quick without triggers?